# Excell, compare two columns options, and displaying the result of the 3rd one

Tags: microsoft-excel

My problem is this: i have a table of 3 columns and about 15000 rows of data. I'd like to find a formula or a set of formulas that should compare the pair of the first two columns and if it finds a match with a deviation of 3% to display the values of the 3rd column. So basically, if , let's say it finds the pair 'A52 and B52' that is not bigger or lower then 3% of another pair , let's say 'A3000 and B3000', to display the two values, 'C52', respectively C3000.
Since the values in those 15000 rows are with a lot of digits i am forced to use those (+-)3%.  i hope that is a solution for my problem.

Comment: are you trying to find out whether A52 and B52 are within 3% of each other? How do A3000 and B3000 relate to A52 and B52? Can you give an example using maybe 5-10 rows of data, using the <code> </code> tag, to show what results you are expecting in column 3?

Comment: what im trying to do is: compare the pair formed by the A column and B column (A1,B1) compared to (A2,B2),(A3,B3), (A4,B4).....(A3000,B3000) and so on. It needs to find wheter any pair formed by A and B colums match within the 3% (A1-+3%, B1-+3%),......, (A10-+3%, B10-+3%), ......(A1000-+3%, B1000-+3%),.....,(A3000-+3%, B3000-+3%) to sholw me the pairs that match. To understand better i'll tell u what im trying to accoplish: i have a fotovoltaic plant under supervision for the 3rd year now.

Comment: I can aquire data from this plant, the data is: temperature, radiation and production. So for each hour of the day i get a set of 3 data: temperature, radiation and production. I would like to compare the radiation and temperature (within -/+3%) to see what production was. This way i can tell if over time it decreased the production for the same given condition (temperature and radiatio). Hope its more clear what im trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of what you are trying to do is look at three input data columns (Time, Temperature, Insolation), and compare to a fourth (Production). You want to control for Temperature and Insolation, and determine whether Production varies with Time.

This is a fairly complex statistics exercise, especially as variance of output from PV systems varies only very slowly with time - in the order of 20% loss in production over 20 years, when the variance due to the other variables is much greater and will tend to mask the effect you are looking for.

I think you realise this is a difficult tasks, as you have asked about simplifying the analysis be looking at pairs of temp and insolation that are the same on different days. However, this would result in hundreds of different data pairs, each with a fairly small number of repetitions, and so low individual power for looking for a correlation with time.

Rather than break up the data into several hundred smaller analyses, I'd suggest analysing the whole data set , but trying to isolate the time variable to see whether it has an impact on production.

As I mentioned, to do this properly requires complex statistics, beyond what I have everyday experience applying. But here is a solution you could try that could still tell you what you need without being statistically rigourous:

Assuming the following example data:

```
Time       Temp      Rad    Production
hours        *C     W/m2    W
      1      18      20    3194
      2      20      30    3984
      3      20      40    3976
      4      16      20    3174
      5      14       0       0
      6      10       0       0
      7       8       0       0
      8      10       0       0
      9      14      10    1964
     10      16      20    3136
     11      17      30    3888
     12      18      40    3856
     13      15      30    3824
     14      13      20    3034
     15       5       0       0
     16       8       0       0
     17      12       8    1478
     18      25      15    2263
     19      30      25    2942
     20      30      35    3240
     21      25      20    2712
     22      20      10    1768
     23      22       0       0
     24      18       0       0
     25      22       0       0
     26      25      10    1619
     27      26      20    2539
     28      18      24    2943
     29      12      26    3047
     30      10      18    2427
```

We can build a model that tries to predict Production, given the other 3 variables. Once we find the best fit, we can check whether time was actually an important variable or not, and what rate of decrease it applied.

In this example, I'm going to assume the following equation will give us production:

```
 Production = A*(B*Temp^b)*(C*Rad^c)*(1+D*Time^d)
```

This model assumes variation due to temp and insolation each vary with a power relationship, and time can put a negative slope on the result via D being a small negative number.

Label some cells as A, B, b, C, c, D, d. Then make a new column next to your production data, to calculate new production data from this model. Enter the equation, refering to the recorded data, and the named cells as appropriate. Make the references to named cells fixed using $ notation, then drag/fill down.

At the moment, the model will give errors, as the parameters are zero. So wrap the equation in an iferror(__,0) statement.

Make another column to the right called Error, with formula (Production-Model)^2, and fill down. This is a measure of how far off our model is. Sum that columns values somewhere - it will make a big number. Ideally, this big number will become small later, indicating that our equation works and predicts reality.

Use Solver to alter all the variables, minimising the value of the cell that is the sum of the errors.

At this point, if you graph production over time, and also the modelled production over time, the two should give a good match.
[image]

Of the parameter values found by solver, look at those relating to Time (D and d). If you plot the time part of the model (y=1+D*Time^d) vs time, you'll see the % impact that solver thinks time is having on your production.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will try to understand what you have told me and then put it to work. Hopefully it will give me a start.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have your problem spec correct - ie, you want the result (being the Production value when the Temp is within ±3% of the Radiation) to be displayed in Column D.

Use this formula in Col D and copy it down to the last row.

`=IF(AND(B2>A2*97/100, B2<A2*103/100), C2, "")`

Comment: thank you for your reply. Actualy what i am trying to accomplish is as follows: lets say in one day at some point during the day i have these condition: Radiation 100, temperature +10C and production 500. Another day i have : Radiation 103, temperature +9.55C and production 600. I want that the formula to compare the pair of radiation (100 and 103) then go next to the temperature (+10C and +9.55C) and finding these 2 conditions met to display the results of production: 500, respectively 600.